# Run react-native on Ubuntu and iOS device (app was builded with xcode)

Tags: ios, react-native

I have Mac for work with react-native and I have ubuntu pc for other tasks. I want build react-native app to my physical ios device, but work with code on my ubuntu laptop. Metro server will run on ubuntu.

I know I can change smth in schemas or another place, build app with xcode? connect ios with ubuntu laptop, run metro and I can work not on mac. But I can't find any information about it.

Anybody knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- build your app via xcode to physical device
- disconnect app and connect to other pc (ubuntu for example)
- run react0native metro server on ubuntu machine
- run app and shake device
- enter your local IP
- reload app